# Screw modifier to individual vertices

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

I am beginner to blender

I have only two vertices in 3d viewport of blender
I need to apply screw modifier to only one vertex without modifying the other

Please help me out in this regard

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, it doesn't seem possible, what is the object you're trying to do?

Comment: Nehru boda probably wants to make an animation path.

Answer (score 1):

You need only one vertex for it. Select this vertex. In the Screw modifier tab make an **empty** your **AxisOb**, select an axis and set the remaining params as required. By the way, you can apply this modifier to **any** object, such as a  circle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  I knew that but,  when I have two separate vertices on 3d viewport,  I want the screw modifier to be applied on only one vertex not on the other. The screw modifier is getting applied simultaneously on both vertices